# Generic method with map java

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have Employee class:

```
class Employee {
private String name;
private int salary;
// ...
}
```

I declared and initialized List of `Employee employee`. After it I created the map as u can see bellow:

```
 Map<String, List<Employee>> m = employee.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getName));
```

**The question is,** how to make a generic method which will be printing this map on the screen? I am stuck here, cause I have no idea, what to do with this List.

Was thinking about something like this:

```
public static <K, V> void showVal(Map<K,  List<V>> m) { 
    m.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key (name): " + k + " Salary: " + v) ); 
}
```

The above code gives me just references to employees, how to get a salary using the List in this generic method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bounded generics. That way you can ensure that the values of the map are always some collection of instances of `Employee`:

```
private static <K, V extends Collection<? extends Employee>> void print(Map<K, V> map) {
    map.forEach((name, employees) -> {
        int sum = employees.stream()
                .mapToInt(Employee::getSalary)
                .sum();
        System.out.println("Employee: " + name + " with salary " + sum);
    });
}
```

Also see the official Oracle documentation: [Generic Methods and Bounded Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html)

Comment: The map passed as a argument is declared as `Map<String, List<Employee>>` so it's not working. When I change your code to `showVal(Map<K, List<V>> m)` it does, but there is a problem with `v.getSalary()` <- "cannot find symbol".